# how to check that am i getting my 'jwt' token back in my code?

Tags: typescript, next.js, cookies

> i m trying to get my data that `jwt` actually holds under the hood i
> doing this using `next.js` but the problem is i m getting error
> `error: jwt must be provided` i tried hard but could not find anything
> that why this hapening: here s my code: getMyData.ts this is a
> functiion that is getting using jwt token :

```
    import { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
export const GetDataFromToken = (request:NextRequest)=>{
try { 
    const token = request.cookies.get('secret')?.value||''
    const decodeToken:  any = jwt.verify(token,'secretvslueforauth')
    return decodeToken.id

} catch (error: any) {
    throw new Error(error.message)
}

}
```

> this is the actual route through which i m sending request
> `me.ts`

```
import { connect } from "@/dbConfig/dbConfig";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { GetDataFromToken } from "@/helpers/getDataFromToken";
import User from "@/models/userModel";

// Establish the database connection
connect();

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  try {
    // Get the user ID from the JWT token
    const userId = await GetDataFromToken(request);
    
    // Fetch the user data from the database based on the user ID
    const user = await User.findOne({ id: userId }).select("-password");
console.log(user,"data")
    if (!user) {
      // If the user is not found, you can return an appropriate response
      return NextResponse.json({
        message: "User not found",
      });
    }

    // If user data is found, return it as a JSON response
    return NextResponse.json({
      message: "Success",
      data: user,
    });
  } catch (error: any) {
    // Handle errors and return an appropriate error response
    console.error("Error:", error);
    return NextResponse.json({
      error: error.message,
    });
  }
}
```

> now tell me please what is problem here??

Comment: Can you console.log `token` and tell us what you get?

Comment: i just get null

Answer (score 0):

The error `error: jwt must be provided` shown because the token that you get from cookie is empty!
Catch log from `token` that you get from cookies.

This is important that getting cookies is different in `Server Side` and `Client` in `Next.js` !

Comment: but i have token inside cookies here `const token = request.cookies.get('secret')?.value||''`
but the problem is i m not able to extract back..

Comment: If you use `Next13` you can use this method to get cookie:

`import { cookies } from "next/headers";
    const cookieStore = cookies();
    const token = cookieStore.get('secret');`

Comment: is this just to `get` or both `get` and `set` ??

Comment: You can do both. More docs are here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies

Comment: If you think this is the answer, please choose it as answer. Thanks